# Creating double select dropdown list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, meteor

I want to create double selection dropdown list. User should be able to first select date and then timeslot within one dropdown list. Please see the image. It's pretty much what I'm looking for. The output would be "date + timeslot"
[image: Double selection dropdown list]

I am building a meteor.js app so javascript, jquery, bootstrap, css, etc are the options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What have you try to accomplish this? You can look at some example on google. Search for javascript ios datetime picker

```
http://www.jqueryscript.net/form/iOS-7-Style-jQuery-3D-Animated-Value-Selector-Drumjs.html
```

Comment: Thanks, I simply want to let user's to pick two related items at once. It's much better user experience. It doesn't have to be ios style but preferably something simple.